# Confidence interval of the population mean when variance is known and the sample size is large enough

Tags: statistics, random-variables, variance, confidence-interval

We observe the height of the population of a city as identically distributed random variables and Variance $\sigma^2=7.3$ cm and the mean of the height of 200 randomly chosen inhabitants is 176.2 cm. I need to determine the 99% confidence interval for the average $\mu$. And there is a small note in brackets "(Normal Approximation)".

So my approach so:

$$ 176.2 \pm Z \frac{\sqrt(7.3)}{\sqrt(200)}=176.2 \pm 0.4921 $$

But I am not sure if this was meant by this problem because it seems too simple? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: simply and correct. Just an observation: the variance is a square measure so it cannot be expressed in cm. The std deviation can